# Restore Console Default properties (and help for their Linux equivalents)

Tags: c++, console, console-application

For my Console Application, I needed to prevent user input and window resizing. I used

```cpp
HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
    SetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_SIZEBOX);
```

and

```cpp
void disableInput()
{
    DWORD prev_mode;
    GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &prev_mode);
    SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS |
        (prev_mode & ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE));
}
```

However, after finishing the program, it would be nice to enable these settings again.
I think this

```cpp
void enableInput()
{
    DWORD prev_mode;
    GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &prev_mode);
    SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);
}
```

should work for the input but how do I enable window resizing again?
Also, a little bit off this topic but how to enable/disable console resizing and input for Linux?

Comment: _how do I enable window resizing again?_ Put back the styles you removed before?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I didn't write these code samples myself, I looked for them and adapted them to my problem. I haven't studied how to assign console properties yet and I couldn't find how to reverse the changes.

Comment: Just save the values before you change them and then put them back when you are done with `SetWindowLong`.